# Trying to INNER JOIN in SQL twice to one table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, Flow and Users.  Flow has a list of columns: Username1, Username2, Username3, etc., and some other data I'm fetching (DocumentNumber and Location).

Users has columns for the Username, FirstName, and LastName.

I want to be able to get the FirstName and LastName for all the usernames in Flow with a single query, as well as keep the DocumentNumber and Location.  Is that possible?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can join to the same table multiple times, just give each JOIN a different alias:

```
...
FROM Flow f
LEFT JOIN Users u1 ON f.Username1=u1.Username
LEFT JOIN Users u2 ON f.Username2=u2.Username
LEFT JOIN Users u3 ON f.Username2=u3.Username
...
```

In your select list, refer to u1.FirstName for the first name associated with Username1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply join to the users table multiple times:

```
SELECT 
  f.username,
  u1.firstname,
  u1.lastname,
  u2.firstname,
  u2.lastname,
  u3.firstname,
  u4.lastname,
  f.documentnumber,
  f.location
FROM flow f
INNER JOIN users u1 ON f.username1 = u1.username
INNER JOIN users u2 ON f.username2 = u2.username
INNER JOIN users u3 ON f.username3 = u3.username
```

Comment: Thank you -- this worked brilliantly.  The WHERE clause comes after all this, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
USR.USERNAME AS USERNAME1,
USR1.USERNAME AS USERNAME1,
USR2.USERNAME AS USERNAME1,
FL.DOCUMENTNUMBER,
FL.LOCATION
 FROM
FLOW FL 
INNER JOIN USERS USR ON USR.USERID=FL.USERID
INNER JOIN USERS USR1 ON USR1.USERID=FL.USERID1
INNER JOIN USERS USR2 ON USR2.USERID=FL.USERID2
```